# iphone renew distribution license and provisioning

Tags: iphone, certificate, key, distribution, provisioning

I have an distribution certificate which is expiring next week... then I renewed it today.

Do I have to build another provisioning profile and install it on all devices which is using the provisioning with the "old distribution certificate"?

Or there is nothing to do, and its automatically, after renew certificate?

Thanks!

Comment: I actually wasn't aware that distribution certificates could expire...at least in this short of a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to rebuild, the apps under the old provisioning will expire and no longer will be able to be opened...you have to release a new build under the new certificate

Comment: @BestCoder I dont think he meant for the appstore, rather an adhoc installation, and once your profile expires you need to renew it or create a new one and re distribute your app..